# Spring security - Custom authentication provided not called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

I have read all stackoverflow topics about same issue. I have read baeldung tutorials, yet I'm still not getting this working.

My `CustomAuthenticationProvider` is not being called, hence I get denied access everytime.

I might be missing something obvious as I'm a Spring beginner. But I have read plenty of tutorials and I'm pretty sure I'm doing things as it is supposed to be done.

Below is my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class NovataxewebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/login/**")
            .antMatchers("/resources/**")
            .antMatchers("/sessionTimeout")
            .antMatchers("/logout");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        /* I was trying to do this at the beginning, since it's not working i'm doing something simpler below
          http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login*").anonymous()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/loggedIn")
            .failureUrl("/loginfailed")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remove")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(25);*/

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

And here is the `CustomAuthenticationProvider`. I'm sure it is not going inside thanks to breakpoints inside the authenticate method.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    private static String loginSave;
    private static String passwordSave;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource; 

    @Autowired
    private UsernovaRepository usernovaRepository;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        if(name.matches("")){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(messageSource.getMessage("utilisateur_incorrect", null, Locale.getDefault()));
        }
        UsernovaDAO user = null;
        try {
            user = usernovaRepository.findByUsername(name).get(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(messageSource.getMessage("utilisateur_incorrect", null, Locale.getDefault()));
        }
        String cryptedPass="";
        try {
             cryptedPass = SHA_256_motdepasse(password);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
       if (user!=null && user.getPassword()==null) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
            try {
                user.setPassword(SHA_256_motdepasse(password));
                usernovaRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
                loginSave = name;
                passwordSave = password;
            } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return auth;
        }else if(user!=null&& user.getPassword().equals(cryptedPass)){
            loginSave = name;
            passwordSave = password;
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
            return auth;
        }
        else if(user!=null&& !user.getPassword().matches(cryptedPass)){
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messageSource.getMessage("mot_de_passe_incorrect", null, Locale.getDefault()));
        }
    else {
        }
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(messageSource.getMessage("utilisateur_incorrect", null, Locale.getDefault()));
   }

    public String SHA_256_motdepasse(String passW) throws Exception {
        // this algorithm returns a sha password
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Also I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Security. It is an Apache Tomcat Server.

Comment: What url are you trying to access?

Comment: I just checking your code sample, the provider was called. For more information how to test (especially `httpBasic`) go to the https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security

Comment: Yes !! Thanks a lot, "What url are you trying to access" was the clue. I was trying to access j_spring_security_check ...